# MySQL Hotel Room Price Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I designed a small hotel reservation app, i have trouble with hotel room price query.

So what i want is something like this :

**`normal_price_table`**

```
room_id  | price
1          100
2          120
```

**`season_price_table`**

```
room_id | date      | price
1         2017-08-01    125
1         2017-08-02    125
2         2017-08-01    150 
2         2017-08-02    150
```

I'am looking for a SQL query that will have this result :

**Query 1 : Get room price between 2017-08-01 and 2017-08-04**
This is 2 days of normal price + 2 days of season price

```
room_id |  price
1          450 ( 200 normal price + 2* 125 season price)
2          540 ( 240 normal price + 2* 150 season price)
```

**Query 2 : Get room price between 2017-08-06 and 2017-08-09**
This is 4 day normal price

```
room_id |  price
1          400 ( 4 * 100 normal price )
2          480 ( 4 * 120 normal price )
```

Any guide and help on how to achieve this query is appreciated !
Thank You !

Comment: Do you store a price for every day (which would be nuts, BTW), or just the first day of each season?

Comment: This seems to be impossible with a single query, as you can't loop inside a MySQL query. This would be much more fit for a procedure.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks :) but could not edit it so removed it.

Comment: You want in your first query normal price + season price . But your normal price does not match your normal price so come this from the normal price table?

Comment: @Noob thenormal price is match i think , can you explain which part i missed ?

Comment: @Strawberry yes i think its need some advanced procedure or other sql technique , this is why i ask..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Questions without any demonstration of own efforts are not well received as you can see from the down and close votes.

Comment: It wasn't a yes/no question.

Comment: @Vilsol Unless you have some special insight, comments of that nature tend to be counter-productive.

Comment: `25-2017-10` is not a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the sum of season prices and normal price multiplied with number of normal days. The number of normal days is the DATEDIFF + 1 minus count of the season days.

```
select 
  n.room_id,
  coalesce(sum(s.price), 0) + n.price * (datediff(@to_date, @from_date) - count(s.price) + 1) as price
from normal_price_table n
left join season_price_table s
  on  s.room_id = n.room_id
  and s.date between @from_date and @to_date
group by n.room_id;
```

http://rextester.com/HBLRC69992

If you have a calendar table containing all dates you will ever need in the lifetime of your application, you can simplify the SELECT logic:

```
select n.room_id, sum(coalesce(s.price, n.price)) as price
from normal_price_table n
join calendar c on c.date between @from_date and @to_date
left join season_price_table s
  on  s.room_id = n.room_id
  and s.date    = c.date
group by n.room_id;
```

http://rextester.com/ZDR40157

Comment: This is correct and also very clean, the only difference is i had to add `group by n.room_id,n.price` otherwise its not working on newer mysql install with enforce full_groping. Thank You !

Comment: @todiadiyatmo I've assumed that `n.room_id` is the primary key (IMHO it should be). In that case the query should work on newer versions, because MySQL now has [Detection of Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html#functional-dependence-keys).

Answer (score 0):

Below will be the query for it

**Query 1: Get room price between 2017-08-01 and 2017-08-04** This is 2 days of normal price + 2 days of season price

```
SELECT X.room_id, SUM(X.price) as price
FROM
(
    SELECT
      np.room_id,
      (SUM(np.price) * ( SELECT COUNT(0) FROM season_price_table spt1 WHERE 
                         spt1.date >= '2017-08-01'
                         AND spt1.date <= '2017-08-04'
                         AND spt1.room_id = np.room_id)) as price
      FROM normal_price_table np GROUP BY np.room_id
    UNION
    SELECT spt.room_id, SUM(spt.price) as price
    FROM season_price_table spt
    WHERE spt.date >= '2017-08-01' and spt.date <= '2017-08-04'
    GROUP BY spt.room_id
) X GROUP BY X.room_id
```

**Query 2: Get room price between 2017-08-06 and 2017-08-10** This is 4 day normal price

```
SELECT np.room_id,
       (SUM(np.price) * ( SELECT COUNT(0) FROM season_price_table spt1 
                           WHERE spt1.date >= '2017-08-06'
                           AND spt1.date <= '2017-08-10' 
                           AND spt1.room_id = np.room_id)) as price
FROM normal_price_table np GROUP BY np.room_id
```